# Animation with white background is not working

Tags: html, css

I am setting a simple animation for a button.

```css
@keyframes test {
  from {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  to {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

button {
  animation-name: test;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<button style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: white;">button</button>
```

When the button has a white background color the animation is invisible. When the button has a red background color the animation is visible. Why?

Comment: the code above works good, can you be more clear with the issue please?

Comment: See an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/h4brev1z/
The first button doesn't change background color, but the second does.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have shared the correct link, but in the above link, both the buttons change colour.

Comment: Very strange, on Firefox it is working, but on Chrome not.